# Android Service for uploading data for x minute in every x minute

Tags: android, loops, service

I have 2 service running in background. One that will constantly collect location data and another to send data to server that will be start by AlarmManager every 10 minutes.

In the service that send data to server, I have a method that will post data (50 rows from database) in `onStartCommand()`. I'd like to have the service execute the the post data method continuously for up to 5 minutes.

I have tried to use a while loop to execute the method continuously but it will show message that app is not responding. I think that the while loop is executing the method in service non-stop in Main thread causing the activity to crash.

Is there any better way to execute a method continuously in a service while to crashing activity on the main thread?

Comment: Its a deathwish for battery life

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do your work on another thread.

The service helps control the lifecycle outside of the UI, but it is still on the MainThread.

It is called a "background service" as it has a background lifecycle which is different to you Activity lifecycle.

Simplest example is spawn an `ASyncTask` from your background `Service` or better use an `IntentService`. An `IntentService` will automatically control your use of threads.

Here is the official documentation for Intent Service thread work:

http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/send-request.html

And here are the API docs for what I discussed
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Answer (score 1):

> I have 2 service running in background. One that will constantly collect location data and another to send data to server that will be start by AlarmManager every 10 minutes.

This will be terrible for battery life, as you will need to keep the CPU constantly powered on via a `WakeLock` to "constantly collect location data".

> In the service that send data to server, I have a method that will post data (50 rows from database) in onStartCommand(). I'd like to have the service execute the the post data method continuously for up to 5 minutes.

This will be even worse for battery life, as now you will keep the WiFi or mobile radios in a high-power state continuously for up to 5 minutes.

> Is there any better way to execute a method continuously in a service while to crashing activity on the main thread?

Fork a background thread.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You have said that constantly collecting data and sending data for up to 5 minutes will be battery consuming, how can I change the application to improve the battery life?

Comment: @user2763829: Well, your big limiting factor is keeping the CPU on for your location collection. Unless you are going to change that particular requirement, battery life will be lousy. Beyond that, when there is enough data to be worth sending, have your *first* service fork a thread to do the disk and network I/O necessary to send it. In particular, do your network I/O in short pulses with as long of time in between those pulses as possible. The every-10-minutes `AlarmManager` and second service can then go away.

Comment: @user2763829: You need a background thread for the disk and network I/O anyway -- network I/O will crash outright on Android 4.0+ devices if you try doing it on the main application thread. I would suggest reading [the training guide on battery-efficient data transfers](http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/index.html) to learn more tips regarding your data uploads.

Comment: The app will be used for activity recognition so constant logging data will be required. What I am trying to do now is every 10 minutes start a service and check if the device is connected to wifi, if connected to wifi only send 50 rows of data using http post via asynctask continuously for up to 5 minutes, else stop the service.

I will read the provided links! thanks!